# Set the value of custom field when post is published or updated

Tags: save-post, post-meta

I'm trying to set the value of custom fields when a custom post type ('film') is published or updated. The end goal is to get meta-data from an API based on a URL field when the post is published or updated.

I tried to use `add_action( 'save_post_film', 'get_film_data', 10, 2 );`, with the following function :

```
function get_film_data( $post_id ) {

    // If this is just a revision, don't send the email.
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
        return;

    $value = 'something'; // The value depends in fact on the value of another field
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'some_custom_field', $value);
}
```

This only works when a new post is created. The custom field's value is already set when the edit form opens. But for some reason it doesn't work once the post has been published.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: On top of my head this should totally work, save hooks fire pretty much _always_ (outside of some edge cases like scheduled posts).

Comment: For some reason the hook I used (for custom post types) doesn't work the same way as save_post. Could be a bug ?

Comment: That would be _very_ strange since the two hooks are right next to each other in code and are pretty much identical outside of name. I can't think of how it would possibly break in this way really. Probably impossible to say without hands on debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like [`save_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) doesn't work the way you currently have your `add_action`.

According to the Codex, you need to run your function on `save_post` and check the post type in the function.

```
function get_film_data( $post_id ) {

   if ( get_post_type($post_id) == 'film' ) {

        // If this is just a revision, don't send the email.
        if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
        return;

        $value = 'something'; // The value depends in fact on the value of another field
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'some_custom_field', $value);

    }

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'get_film_data', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: I thought the same initially, but WP started to have post type based filters. Reference: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3499

Comment: It seems like save_post_{custom_post_type} doesn't behave the same way as save_post. With your code things work as expected indeed.